# Bash variable substitution problem

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a problem with variable substitution in bash. I'm doing like as explained in below code, but cd $d is not going into original directory i.e. after expanding $var

```
export var="/a/b/c"
for d \`cat file.f`; do
cd $d
done
```

file.f:

```
$var/aa/bb/cc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `eval`:

```
export var="/a/b/c"
for d in $(cat file.f)
do
    eval echo "$d"
    eval cd $d
    pwd
done
```

or better still, using read:

```
export var="/a/b/c"
while read d
do
        eval echo "$d"
        eval cd "$d"
        pwd
done < file.f
```

Comment: Don't use `cat` like this, it's dangerous and also introduces additional needless redirect. Use `<"file.f" while read d; do...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ var="/home/durrantm/a/b/c"
$ cd $var
$ pwd
/home/durrantm/a/b/c
```

Comment: I think the idea is that there can be a list of directory names in file.f